# XmlSerializerInputFormatter is obsolete - ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xml-serialization, asp.net-core-2.1

I am using the following to accept XML serialized in my Core API App.

```cs
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    // allow xml format for input
    options.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerInputFormatter());
}).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

After updating to ASP.NET Core 2.1 I receive the following warning:

> 'XmlSerializerInputFormatter.XmlSerializerInputFormatter()' is obsolete: 'This constructor is obsolete and will be removed in a future version.'

What is the new way to handle this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Mvc/Mvc.Formatters.Xml/src/XmlSerializerInputFormatter.cs#L67), there's a constructor that has *not* been marked as `Obsolete`:

```cs
public XmlSerializerInputFormatter(MvcOptions options)
```

This constructor takes an instance of `MvcOptions`, so you can pass through your existing `options` argument:

```cs
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    // allow xml format for input
    options.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerInputFormatter(options));
}) ...
```

As of ASP.NET Core 3.0, this constructor is the only one available. Those that were marked obsolete have now been removed.

Comment: No problem. I just checked against the 2.0 source and the constructor I mentioned is new in ASP.NET Core 2.1. Here's the [Github Issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6858) that the pull-request for this change links to.

Answer (score 5):

With .NET Core 2.2 or later XmlSerializerInputFormatter should be marked as deprecated.

Instead a of explicitly defining XML serializers as we did before, in the .NET Core 2.2 we can add them simply by calling AddXmlSerializerFormatters() method which will do the job now. Read [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/7715) why it has been deprecated

Here is how you can do it.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(config =>
    {
        config.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
        config.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;

        config.OutputFormatters.Add(new CsvOutputFormatter());
    }).AddXmlSerializerFormatters().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```